# Issue with Firebase deployment

Tags: node.js, firebase

Obviously I am missing something (!)obvious but I simply cannot deploy my app to firebase. I am following this google guide for progressive web apps. Web server didn't work for me ( to access my app from other devices ), so I tried using firebase as was suggested in the end of the guide. I follow the directions, everything executes with no issues and all I get at the end is "Welcome to Firebase hosting" default message. I am using linux, here is what I did:

- Installed firebase tools with "sudo npm install -g firebase-tools"
- Went to project root directory and used "firebase init". I selected hosting, typed in "/" as public directory and chose the configure for single page option. Everything worked fine.
- Typed "firebase deploy" and again everything completed with no errors. No result.
- Tried adding manually all my project files (Firebase dashboard - Storage). Still nothing.

I also read their guide, but didn't find any steps I missed or failed. So what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: If you run `firebase deploy --debug` it will provide more detailed output. My suggestion would be to re-run `firebase init` with a public directory of `.` instead of `/` - as the deploy might be failing because you're trying to deploy the root of your file system. Finally, make sure you refresh the page and clear your browser cache after the deploy to see changes.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks for the tip, makes total sense.

Comment: @ChrisRaynor Thank you for your suggestion. Worked for me too. I had an older firebase project that worked on an earlier version of firebase-tools with public directory of '/'. It appears that the new version of firebase-tools has changed this behavior and does not work anymore. I was having EACCES issues due to this.